# Sorting Datatables by Using Checked Rows

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, datatables

I have a table using datatables. It contains a checkbox on first column. How can I sort the table so when a checkbox is checked, the checked row should go on top?

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead align='center'><tr><th></th><th>Alphabet</th><th>Numeric</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody align='center'>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value=1></td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value=2></td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value=3></td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: there is only one checked row or multiple rows can be checked?

Comment: multiple rows can be checked

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your DataTables initialization call, as it's difficult to tell if you're just creating this HTML table or if this is the result of the DataTables execution.

Answer (score 0):

The `order` [option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) probably has what you are searching for. The usage of this call is as follows (from the linked documentation):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    /*Other initialization options go here*/
    //sort by column 0 ascending and then by column 1 ascending
    "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ], [ 1, 'asc' ]]
} );
```

You can sort by as many columns as you need, so if you want to sort by some other column value and still have checked rows appear at the top, simply put the checkbox column first in the list of arrays and then the other column you want to sort by.

This solution assumes that you are using DataTables checkboxes and not just adding HTML checkboxes to your table afterwards. If you aren't currently using DataTables checkboxes I'd encourage you to, [here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/api/checkbox.html) is a link to the example page for how to initialize those (note that this documentation is for the paid Editor extension to DataTables but the checkboxes themselves will work without the Editor extension).

Doing it this way will persist the sorting through searches, but note that if you do not turn off [manual ordering](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering) (`ordering: false`) then the user will be able to remove your default ordering and replace it with one of their own.